# Partial template specialization based on lval/rval?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, rvalue-reference

I'm writing an adaptor class to allow me to write this:

```
for (auto item : ButFirst(myvec)) { ... }
```

The following class definition works well when, as above, the argument is an lval:

```
template <typename Container>
class ButFirst {
  const Container& container_;
public:
 ButFirst(const Container& container) : container_(container) {}
  typename Container::const_iterator begin() { return ++(container_.begin()); }
  typename Container::const_iterator end() { return container_.end(); }
};
```

However, I want to also use it when the argument is an rval, as in:

```
for (auto item : ButFirst(get_vec(3)) { ... }
```

I would therefore write the following class definition:

```
template <typename Container>
class ButFirst {
   const Container container_;

public:
  ButFirst(Container&& container) : container_(std::move(container)) {}
...
};
```

How can I write one class definition that handles both?  Or maybe one class and some partial template specializations?

Comment: `ButFirst(const Container& container)`  should work for both since we can hold an rvalue reference into a const reference.

Comment: @martin reference lifetime extension isn't long enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename Container>
class ButFirst {
  Container container_;
public:
  ButFirst(Container container) : container_(std::forward<Container>(container)) {}
  typename std::decay_t<Container>::const_iterator begin() { return std::next(container_.begin()); }
  typename std::decay_t<Container>::const_iterator end() { return container_.end(); }
};
```

then add deduction guide:

```
template <typename Container>
ButFirst(Container&&)->ButFirst<Container>;
```

and  ... poof.

Despite appearances this only copies on rvalues.

The forwarding reference in the `ButFirst` deduction guide deduces `Container` to be a reference type when you construct it with an lvalue, and `Container` as a value type when you pass it an rvalue.  This is exactly what you want.

And that isn't a coincidence; forwarding references work that way for a reason.

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/a5oKPf7bv).

As an aside, my version of this is a bit different.

I define a `range_view` type that can be constructed from a range-like, and stores 2 iterators.

`range_view` methods like `begin()` are `const`; `range_view` is like a pointer, not like a value.

It has methods:

```
range_view except_front(std::size_t n=1)const;
range_view except_back(std::size_t n=1)const;
range_view only_front(std::size_t n=1)const;
range_view only_back(std::size_t n=1)const;
```

which clamp `n` based on how big the range is.

Then:

```
for(auto item: range_view(container).except_front())
```

does what yours does.

I consider checking for iterator counting errors and returning empty range in that case well worth the overhead for the reliability I get from it, as that math happens once per loop, not once per iteration.

Also, `range_view` has ridiculously many other useful uses.

Comment: Amazing.  I would have thought that because container_ is not of reference type, it could not refer to the same object as the lvalue refers to.

Comment: If the lvalue is not copied then I should be able to mutate the original lvalue and see the effect on the ButFirst object, yes? 
     vector<int> myvec{1,2};
     ButFirst<vector<int>> bf(myvec);
     myvec.push_back(3);
But I don't see the 3 when I iterate using bf.  This seems to suggest that the lvalue is copied.

Comment: @pnklein https://godbolt.org/z/a5oKPf7bv -- you do know that `for(:)` loops create the begin/end iterators when they start iterating, right?  So once you start iterating, editing the underlying container can lead to horribly bad things, including missing push backs, dangling pointers, etc.  The reason why `container_` is a reference is that forwarding references `T&&`  when passed lvalues deduce `T` as a reference type.

Comment: Yes, I was trying it before starting the iteration.  This is amazing.  I've learned so much from your response.  Do you recommend any reading on this topic (aside from the standard and the proposals that led to it)? And could you share your range_view code?